# Problem with importing NONNA-100 bathymetry data into QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, bathymetry, canada

Total QGIS newbie.

Tried importing Canadian Hydrographic Service Non-Navigational (NONNA-100) Bathymetric Data found here https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/d3881c4c-650d-4070-bf9b-1e00aabf0a1d

Followed the Web Map Service (WMS) connection instructions found here: https://pacgis01.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/FGPPublic/NONNA_100/How_to_access_and_download_CHS_NONNA_100_on_FGP_en.pdf

Data seems to import into a QGIS but doesn't look anything like the bathymetric map.

Coordinate reference system displayed in the QGIS is: WGS 84 EPSG: 4326

QGIS version 3.14

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  You say "_but doesn't look anything like the bathymetric map_" - but what does it actually look like?  Can you please [edit] your question to include a screenshot to show how it looks, and explain what you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS (3.14) WMS

```
https://gisp.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/FGP/CHS_NONNA_100/MapServer
```

There are two

> CHS NONNA-100 Bathymetric Data / Les produits de données
> bathymétriques NONNA-100 du SHC

services

[image]